# Improve compression ratio via zopfli

Tags: gzip, zopfli

1) I have seen improvement in the compression ratio for gzip using zopfli. However, the again seems to limited by approximately 5%. Is there any mechanism by which compression ratio can be further improved. Are there any configuration parameters which can be changes in zopfli to improve compression ratio

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

gzip does not use zopfli, so you might be using [pigz](https://zlib.net/pigz/) or something else. pigz provides options to change the tuning parameters of zopfli, which you *might* be able to use to improve compression on your particular data. Look at the `--iterations`, `--maxsplits`, `--oneblock`, and `--first` options of pigz.

Comment: Thanks...Are there any test which suggest improvement in compression ratio? I will try to compare the results with gzip and zopfli

Comment: The only test is to compare the sizes of the results after compression.

Comment: i did a comparison, but could not see any difference in size. I used -11 option. Can you let me know if this is the correct option?

Comment: Yes, those options must be used in combination with `-11`.